# What is the probability of a rolling 8 biased dice to get a sum of 28?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

You roll 8 6-sided dice. What is the probability that the sum is 28?

Given that the P(1)=8/117, P(2)=14/117, P(3)=34/117, P(4)=39/117, P(5)=14/117, and P(6)=8/117

At first I've been trying to find the permutations of rolling 8 dice to get a sum of 28 but I don't know if the order matters so I tried to find combinations as well. Having found the permutations and combinations, because the probabilities are different for each number, I don't know how to find the probability for each combination/permutation.

Please explain it in detail if you can. Thank you

Comment: this site’s user expect You to include Your own attempt in the question. Let us know where did You get stuck, what did You not understand, etc..

Comment: A method is to find the coefficient of $x^{28}$ in polynomial $(\sum_{i=1}^6P(i)x^i)^8$. Quite a job, I think.

Comment: Thank you drhab

Comment: But @drhab? What if the probabilities are the "without replacement" scenario?

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean in this context with "without replacement". By throwing dice the question "with or without replacement" does not show up.

Comment: But say you have a bag containing cards that are numbered from 1 to 6. A person picks out 8 cards, what is the probability that the sum is 28 without replacements, given that the probabilities for individual values are the same as above?

Comment: That can only be answered if we know how many cards (of each kind) there are in the bag. Are there 117 cards in total maybe? The probabilities mentioned in your question point in that direction.

Comment: Yes. There are 117 cards. The numerators in the probabilities are the frequencies for the corresponding values of the cards.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I provided. Actually it is not an answer to the posed question but to questions posed in comments.

Comment: Thank you @drhab

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
\eqalign{
  & 1^{\,8}  = \left( {p_{\,1}  + \,p_{\,2}  + \, \cdots \, + p_{\,6} } \right)^{\,8}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} } \hfill  \cr    {k_{\,1}  + \,k_{\,2}
  + \, \cdots \, + k_{\,6}  = \,8} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{  8 \cr   k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots \,,k_{\,6}  \cr}  \right)
 p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } \,p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} } \, \cdots \,p_{\,6} ^{\,k_{\,6} } }  \cr} 
$$

Then consider the polynomial
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {p_{\,1} x^{\,1}  + \,p_{\,2} x^{\,2}  + \, \cdots \, + p_{\,6} x^{\,6} } \right)^{\,8}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} } \hfill  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + \,k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots \, + k_{\,6}  = \,8} \hfill  \cr  } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{
  8 \cr 
  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots \,,k_{\,6}  \cr}  \right)\left( {p_{\,1} x^{\,1} } \right)^{\,k_{\,1} } 
 \,\left( {p_{\,2} x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,k_{\,2} } \, \cdots \,\left( {p_{\,6} x^{\,6} } \right)^{\,k_{\,6} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} } \hfill  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + \,k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots \, + k_{\,6}  = \,8} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{
  8 \cr 
  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots \,,k_{\,6}  \cr}  \right)\left( {p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } \,p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} }
  \, \cdots \,p_{\,6} ^{\,k_{\,6} } } \right)x^{\,1 \cdot k_{\,1}  + 2 \cdot k_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + 6 \cdot k_{\,6} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{8\, \le \,m\, \le \,48}
 {\left( {\;\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + \,k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots \, + k_{\,6}  = \,8}  \cr 
   {\,1 \cdot k_{\,1}  + 2 \cdot k_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + 6 \cdot k_{\,6}  = m}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {\left( \matrix{
  8 \cr 
  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots \,,k_{\,6}  \cr}  \right)\left( {p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } \,p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} }
  \, \cdots \,p_{\,6} ^{\,k_{\,6} } } \right)} } \right)x^{\,m} }  \cr} 
$$

For $x=1$ the polynomial has value $1$.
So clearly the probability you are looking for is the coefficient of $x^{28}$ in the above identity
which is
$$
\left[ {x^{\,28} } \right] = 0.11278 \ldots 
$$
The plot of all the coefficients, compared with case of $p_k = const. = 1/6$, is as given below.

[image: Multin_prob_1]

You are further asking for the case without replacement.
It is not clear what kind of process you want actually to simulate.

If you mean that you can extract only once any of six tickets labelled $[1,6]$, then clearly you cannot do more than six extractions.

However I will expose briefly the principles underlying the construction of a 
[Ordinary Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function_(OGF))

Consider to expand the following polynomial
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(x) = \left( {1 + x} \right)\left( {1 + x^{\,2} } \right) \cdots \left( {1 + x^{\,q} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  =  \cdots  + 1 \cdot x^{\,k_{\,1} }  \cdot  \ldots  \cdot x^{\,k_{\,2} }  \cdot 1 \cdot  \ldots  \cdot x^{\,k_{\,m} }  +  \cdots  \cr} 
$$
it clearly represents all the cases in which, out of $q$ tickets, some are extracted only once ($k_1 \ne k_2$ etc.), and
the remaining are not extracted at all (the $1=x^0$).

If the probability of being extracted are different, then consider
$$
F(x) = \left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,1} } \right) + p_{\,1} x} \right)\left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,2} } \right) + p_{\,2} x^{\,2} } \right) \cdots \left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,q} } \right) + p_{\,q} x^{\,q} } \right)
$$
where $F(1) = 1$.

Finally pass to
$$
G(x,y) = \left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,1} } \right) + p_{\,1} yx} \right)\left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,2} } \right) + p_{\,2} yx^{\,2} } \right) \cdots \left( {\left( {1 - p_{\,q} } \right) + p_{\,q} yx^{\,q} } \right)
$$
it should be clear what the coefficient of $y^n$ represents, and what is the coefficient of $y^n x^m$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me have some time to process that

Comment: What are k and x?

Comment: @JerryVu $k_j$ is the number of dice showing the face $j$.  $x^j$ is a "phantom" variable needed to account for the sum of the shown values.

Comment: Thank you G Cab

Comment: G Cab, what about in the scenario that it is 'without replacement'? 'Without replacement' doesn't work for dice but say if you picked from a bag for a number with the same probabilities as above, given that the possible values are also from 1 to 6? The classic n-1 denominator for the incrementing probabilities doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: So I tried expanding this to find the coefficient: (x*8/117+x^2*14/116+x^3*34/115+x^4*39/114+x^5*14/113+x^6*8/112)^8

Comment: But the answers are not correct for without replacements

Comment: @JerryVu: I did my best to cope with your non-clear requirements

Comment: I'll take time to research more what an ordinary function is. I'm a high school student so I'm not up to that level yet. But in the meantime, thank you for bearing with me, G Cab.

Comment: @JerryVu: I see, as a young student you have all my sympathy ! the matter is that the question you posed cannot be answered in an easier way than by o.g.f.

Answer (score 0):

In answer on your comment concerning "without replacement".

Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)\in S$ if and only if the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers that satisfy:

$$\sum_{i=1}^6a_i=8\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^6ia_i=28$$

Then to be found is:$$\sum_{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)\in S}\frac{\binom{8}{a_1}\binom{14}{a_2}\binom{34}{a_3}\binom{39}{a_4}\binom{14}{a_5}\binom{8}{a_6}}{\binom{117}{8}}$$

It is like taking $8$ notes from an urn that contains $8$ notes with number $1$ on it, $14$ with number $2$ on it, et cetera.

Favourable outcomes give  $28$ as summation of all drawn numbers.

So essential here is finding the set $S$.

Again that could be quite a job on its own.